Some doubts regarding topological vector spaces
I am currently studying topological vector spaces and I would like to clear up some doubts.

We know that, in a topological vector space $X$, $U$ is a neighborhood of zero iff $U + a$ is a neighborhood of $a$ for every $a \in X$. That means that it suffices to work with neighborhoods of zero to see the properties of the neighborhoods of any point. Does this property also allow me to simplify also the notion of convergence in some sense?

For example, if a topological vector space is metrizable, continuity is the same as sequential continuity, so can we prove that scalar multiplication is continuous by considering $\lambda_n \to \lambda$ and $x_n \to 0$ and seeing that $\lambda_n x_n \to 0$? Why?

When proving that a Cauchy sequence is bounded in a topological vector space, why do we need balanced neighborhoods?

If a vector space is endowed with a metric which is traslation invariant, what are the similarities with a topological vector space? What can we say about the neighborhoods, continuity of addition, ...?

Why in a topological vector space $x_n \to x$ iff $x_n - x \to 0?$ Is it because in topological vector spaces addition is continuous so it is sequentially continuous and therefore if we take the sequences $x_n$ and constant $-x$ and sum them we have that $x_n - x \to x-x = 0$?


That property also holds for nets, which is a more general case. In this case, we use a result which states that a map $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff for every net $x_s$ that converges to $x_0$,  $f(x_s)$ converges to $f(x_0)$, don't we?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

A friendly warning: 1. By the standards of this site, a "question" should not contain multiple question. You may have your "question" closed as needing more focus. People will also avoid answering such "questions" and / or downvote your question. 2. Comments are not long discussion nor to introduce additional questions.

See your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5001352/exercise-on-complex-measures/5002256#5002256  . The long sequence of comments probably attracted  the attention of Moderation, who closed your question and downvoted my answer.  Useless to debate with Moderation. I hope you now understand way some of your question get no answer.
