Exercise on complex measures
Let $(\nu_n)$ be a sequence of complex measures defined on $(X, \Sigma)$. Prove the following:

There exists a positive and finite measure $\mu$ such that $\nu_n \ll \mu$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of $X$ that generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$, prove that $\nu_1(A) = \nu_2(A)$ for all $ A \in \mathcal{A}$ implies $\nu_1 = \nu_2$.

If $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $\Sigma = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\nu_1((-\infty, a]) = \nu_2((-\infty, a])$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\nu_1 = \nu_2$.

If $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $\Sigma = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, there exists a unique complex measure $\nu$ defined on the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that for all $A, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$,
$$
\nu(A \times B) = \nu_1(A) \nu_2(B).
   $$


My attempt
Question 1
We know that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the total variation $|\nu_n|$ is a finite positive measure that is absolutely continuous with respect to the measure $\nu_n$.
Let us set
$$ \mu(A) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{|\nu_n|(A)}{1 + |\nu_n|(X)}. $$
We have that $\mu$ is a measure:

$\mu $ is non-negative.
$\mu(\emptyset) = 0. $
$ \mu $ is countably additive:

Suppose $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty} $ is a countable collection of disjoint sets in $ \Sigma $. We need to show
$$
\mu\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_i).
$$
First, we observe
$$
\mu\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{|\nu_n|\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right)}{1 + |\nu_n|(X)}.
$$
Using the fact that $ \{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty} $ are disjoint sets, we have
$$
|\nu_n|\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\nu_n|(A_i),
$$
since $ |\nu_n| $ is a measure and satisfies countable additivity. Therefore:
$$
\mu\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\nu_n|(A_i)}{1 + |\nu_n|(X)}.
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{|\nu_n|(A_i)}{1 + |\nu_n|(X)}.
$$
We now apply the Tonelli's Theorem (since the terms are non-negative) to interchange the sums:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{|\nu_n|(A_i)}{1 + |\nu_n|(X)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\nu_n|(A_i)}{1 + |\nu_n|(X)}.
$$
Thus, we get:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\nu_n|(A_i)}{1 + |\nu_n|(X)} = \mu\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right).
$$
Besides, $\mu$ is finite because of the convergence of the series and absolutely continuous with respect to $|\nu_n|, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$
Question 2
Note that if $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra, that means that $\mathcal{A}$ is a ring and the total set $X$ is in $\mathcal{A}$.
We know that as a result of the Jordan decomposition Theorem, each measure $\nu_i$ can be written in the form:
$$\nu_i = \nu_i^1 - \nu_i^2 +i(\nu_i^3 - \nu_i^4),$$
where $\nu_i^j$ with  $j\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ is a positive and finite mesure. To apply Carathéodory extension Theorem for each of these mesures we need that they are $\sigma$-finite. Indeed, this property holds:
$$ X = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n, $$
where $A_n = X$ for $n=1$ and $A_n = \emptyset$ for $n \neq 1$ and $\nu_i^j(X) < \infty$.
However, is it true that if
$$\nu_1^1 - \nu_1^2 +i(\nu_1^3 - \nu_1^4) = \nu_2^1 - \nu_2^2 +i(\nu_2^3 - \nu_2^4),$$
then $\nu_1^j = \nu_2^j $ for each $j\in\{1,2,3,4\}$?
Question 3
For this question, I struggle to find the correct algebra. One could think of
$$ \mathcal{A} = \{ (-\infty, a] : a \in \mathbb{Q} \}, $$
but it turns out that this set is not an algebra. Therefore, although $\mathcal{A}$ generates the Borel sets, we cannot conclude.
Question 4
Do I have to use the same idea as in Question 2 and then use the following theorem?
Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{S}, \nu)$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. There exists a unique measure defined on the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma \otimes \mathcal{S}$ generated by the products $M \times N$, where $M \in \Sigma$ and $N \in \mathcal{S}$, denoted by $\mu \otimes \nu$, such that for all $A \in \Sigma$ and $B \in \mathcal{S}$, we have:
$$
(\mu \otimes \nu)(A \times B) = \mu(A)\nu(B).
$$
But, how would I do that explicitly?
Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Question 1. Your proof is correct.
Question 2.  We start by proving that:

If $\nu_1(X) = \nu_2(X)$, then
$\mathcal{D} = \{ E \in \Sigma :  \nu_1(E) = \nu_2(E) \} $ is a Dynkin system ($\lambda$-system).

Proof

Clearly, $\emptyset \in  \mathcal{D}$.

If $E \in \mathcal{D}$ then $\nu_1(E) = \nu_2(E)$, so
$$\nu_1(E^c) = \nu_1(X \setminus E) = \nu_1(X) - \nu_1(E) = \nu_2(X) - \nu_2(E) =  \nu_2(X \setminus E)= \nu_2(E^c)$$
So $E^c \in \mathcal{D}$.

For $n\in\Bbb N$, if $E_n\in\mathcal{D}$ are pairwise disjoint then, since for $n\in\Bbb N$, $\nu_1(E_n)= \nu_2(E_n)$
$$\nu_1 \left (\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\nu_1(E_n)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\nu_2(E_n) = \nu_2 \left (\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n \right)$$
So, $\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n  \in \mathcal{D}$.


So $\mathcal{D} = \{ E \in \Sigma :  \nu_1(E) = \nu_2(E) \} $ is a $\lambda$-system.
$\square$
Now, let $\mathcal{A}$ be any $\pi$-system of subsets of $X$ (that means that $\mathcal{A}$ is not empty and is closed by finite intersections),
such that $X \in \mathcal{A}$ (a particular case is when $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra). If $\nu_1(A) = \nu_2(A)$ for all $ A \in \mathcal{A}$, then  $\nu_1(X) = \nu_2(X)$ and, by the previous result,
$\mathcal{D} = \{ E \in \Sigma :  \nu_1(E) = \nu_2(E) \} $ is a $\lambda$-system. Clearly, $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{D}$.
Since $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\pi$-system of subsets of $X$, we know, by Sierpiński-Dynkin's π- theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Sierpi%C5%84ski%E2%80%93Dynkin's_%CF%80-%CE%BB_theorem ), that $\sigma(\mathcal{A}) \subseteq \mathcal{D}$. So, being $\Sigma = \sigma(\mathcal{A}) $, we have $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{D}$. It means, for all $A \in \Sigma$, $\nu_1(A)=\nu_2(A)$, that is $\nu_1 =\nu_2$.
prove that $\nu_1(A) = \nu_2(A)$ for all $ A \in \mathcal{A}$ implies $\nu_1 = \nu_2$.
Question 3. If $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $\Sigma = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\nu_1((-\infty, a]) = \nu_2((-\infty, a])$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, then
$$ \nu_1(\mathbb{R}) = \lim_{\substack {a \to +\infty \\ a \in \Bbb Q}} \nu_1((-\infty, a])= \lim_{\substack {a \to +\infty \\ a \in \Bbb Q}} \nu_2((-\infty, a])= \nu_2(\mathbb{R})$$
Let $\mathcal{A} = \{(-\infty,a] : a \in \Bbb Q\} \cup \{\Bbb R\}$. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\pi$-system, $\Bbb R \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\nu_1(A) = \nu_2(A)$ for all $ A \in \mathcal{A}$. Moreover $\sigma(\mathcal{A})= \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. So, by our result in Question 2, we have that $\nu_1=\nu_2$
Question 4. Note that $\mathcal{A} = \{ A \times B : A, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a $\pi$-system and  $\Bbb R^2 \in \mathcal{A}$, so the uniqueness of the measure $\nu$ is a direct consequence of our result in Question 2.
The existence follows from the standard theorems to extend a premeasure defined on a semi-ring to a measure.


Question 2. (alternative approach) We start by proving that:

If $\nu_1(X) = \nu_2(X)$, then
$\mathcal{D} = \{ E \in \Sigma :  \nu_1(E) = \nu_2(E) \} $ is a Monotone class

Proof

If $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{D}$ and $A_1 \subseteq  A_2 \subseteq \cdots$, then since for all $i$, $\nu_1(A_i)= \nu_2(A_i)$, we have
$$ \nu_1\left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right ) = \lim_{i \to \infty} \nu_1(A_i)= \lim_{i \to \infty} \nu_2(A_i)= \nu_2\left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right ) $$
So $ \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal{D}$

If $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{D}$ and $A_1 \supseteq  A_2 \supseteq \cdots$, then since for all $i$, $\nu_1(A_i)= \nu_2(A_i)$, and $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are finite measures, we have
$$ \nu_1\left ( \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right ) = \lim_{i \to \infty} \nu_1(A_i)= \lim_{i \to \infty} \nu_2(A_i)= \nu_2\left ( \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right ) $$
So $ \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal{D}$


So $\mathcal{D}$ is a Monotone class.
$\square$
Now, let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra. If $\nu_1(A) = \nu_2(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{D}$. Let $M(\mathcal{A})$ be the smallest Monotone class containing $\mathcal{A}$. It is immediate that $M(\mathcal{A})\subseteq \mathcal{D}$. By the Monotone class theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Monotone_class_theorem_for_sets ), we have
$\Sigma = \sigma(\mathcal{A}) = M(\mathcal{A})\subseteq \mathcal{D}$. It means, for all $A \in \Sigma$, $\nu_1(A)=\nu_2(A)$, that is $\nu_1 =\nu_2$.
Question 3. (alternative approach) We will just present a draft of the proof using Monotone class theorem, instead of using $\pi-\lambda$ theorem.
Let $ \mathcal{C} = \{ (-\infty, a] : a \in \mathbb{Q} \}$.
Step 1.  Let $\mathcal{I} = \mathcal{C}  \cup \{(a, b]: a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } a \leqslant b \} \cup \{ (a, +\infty) : a \in \mathbb{Q} \} \cup \{\Bbb R\}$.
Since $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are finite,we have, for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a \leqslant b$,
$$\nu_1((a, b]) = \nu_1((-\infty, b]) - \nu_1((-\infty, a]) =  \nu_2((-\infty, b]) - \nu_2((-\infty, a])= \nu_2((a, b]) $$
Also, since $\nu_1((-\infty, a]) = \nu_2((-\infty, a])$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, then
$$ \nu_1(\mathbb{R}) = \lim_{\substack {a \to +\infty \\ a \in \Bbb Q}} \nu_1((-\infty, a])= \lim_{\substack {a \to +\infty \\ a \in \Bbb Q}} \nu_2((-\infty, a])= \nu_2(\mathbb{R})$$
Since $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are finite, we have $\nu_1(\mathbb{R}) = \nu_2(\mathbb{R}) < \infty$.
It follows immediately that, for all $a \in \mathbb{Q}$,
$$\nu_1((a, +\infty)) = \nu_1(\Bbb R) - \nu_1((-\infty, a]) =  \nu_2(\Bbb R) - \nu_2((-\infty, a])= \nu_2((a, +\infty)) $$
So, for all $I \in \mathcal{I}$, $\nu_1(I) =\nu_2(I)$.
Step 2. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$. It is easy to see that $A \in \mathcal{A}$ if and only it $A$ is a finite union of disjoint intervals in $\mathcal{I}$. It follows immediately that, for all  $A \in \mathcal{A}$, $\nu_1(A) =\nu_2(A)$.
Step 3. Apply the Monotone class theorem, as we have done to Question 2, and conclude that $\nu_1=\nu_2$ on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, that is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
